# Is there a way to redirect any 404 to the homepage?

Tags: redirection

I understand that Drupal doesn't have a core module to handle redirects and that's *normally* done by the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module, or from the webserver.

But if I want to redirect **any** 404 to the homepage, due to say, a very content-varied site in which it's unlikely to find articles on the same topic, can this be done with Drupal core without editing webserver file?

Comment: This is bad practice, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189169/redirect-to-404-page-or-display-404-message. So don't redirect, instead configure a default not found page as answered by Patrick Kenny. In case you configure the homepage you might want to add a block only visible on the 404 page explaining what is going on: https://www.drupal.org/project/block_in_page_not_found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under **Admin -> Config -> Basic site settings**, you can set the **Default 404 (not found) page**.

URL path: `/admin/config/system/site-information`